# Xamarin Forms Previewer Not Working for Android in Visual Studio Due to Java Version

Tags: java, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I am running...
Visual Studio Community 2017 15.0.0+26228.12
Xamarin 4.3.0.795 (aece090)
Xamarin.Android SDK 7.1.0.43 (3a62f1e)

Running the Forms Previewer for the iOS platform works fine, but once I select the Android platform the following prompt shows on the preview window:

"Something went wrong. Unsupported version of Java detected. The previewer recquires a 64-bit version of Oracle Java JDK 8 (1.8) or higher. Please install it and then set the Java JDK location in the Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio preferences."

I have installed the most recent Java Development Kit (Java SE Development Kit 8u121). It's located in the default location C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_112 and I have pointed it succesfully from with in Visual Studio in Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android Settings->Java Development Kit Location.

I'm not sure what else to do as I have followed the on screen prompt and installed Java JDK 8 multiple times.

Thanks for any suggestions ahead of time!

Comment: 64-bit version is required, are you installing the 32 bit version? i.e. the path you show is `Program Files (x86)`...

Comment: I wondered that too. When I go to Oracle to install java sdk I am in fact selecting the x64 version, the .exe that is downloaded is named "jdk-8u121-windows-x64.exe" the location it recommends installing to is C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_112

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're on Oracle's JDK download page, you need to choose the x64 JDK instead of the x86 JDK. (After installing the 64 bit JDK it should be in C:\Program Files\ not C:\Program Files (x86)\

Comment: I install the Windows x64 named "jdk-8u121-windows-x64.exe" and the location that the installer recommends installing is the following path C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_112.

Comment: The installation path shouldn't matter then as long as you're using the x64 installer... Did you try re-isntalling it? Are you sure the one you installed before was x64 and not x86?

Comment: I'm fairly certain. Looking at my downloads folder I have two .exe one listed as "jdk-8u121-windows-x64.exe" and the other "jdk-8u121-windows-x64 (1).exe". I will try again and manually change the path to the proper "Program Files" location (i do understand that the path doesnt matter if installed properly) and switch that out in Visual Studio Options as well .

Comment: Uninstalling both SDKs 32/64, reinstalling, and repointing to C:\Program Files\Java in Visual Studio seemed to fix it. Thanks.